# VSTO AddIn VB.net UserControl

Tags: excel, vb.net, user-controls, vsto

**Coding in VB.net**

**Custom Usercontrol + Interop - AddIn with Excel**

I have been trying to replicate a refedit box for several forms.

(RefEdit: Control to select ranges as in inputbox)

i would use inputbox but is not practical sin just in one form im attemting to use around 15.

I successfuly added the custom control to the form and i tried the behavior of buttons, but when trying to bind it to excel surprise! i get **System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'** Reffering to Active Workbook.

Seems like Excel.Application is not actually working for a usercontrol.

```
    _xlapp = New Excel.Application
    Xlwb = _xlapp.ActiveWorkbook 'Fires the Exception
    XlAsh = Xlwb.ActiveSheet
```

I have tried to get object thru marshall

```
     Dim _xlapp=Excel.Application
    _xlapp=ctype(GetObject("Excel.Application"),Excel.Application)
     Xlwb = _xlapp.ActiveWorkbook
     XlAsh = Xlwb.ActiveSheet
```

And its the same.

I have also tried to deleting the refereces (desperate tried) in the Usercontrol project so it might be bound to the Addin Active Instance.

Im not really sure how the Interop behaves control level.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no active workbook. Can you write what you get if you do_xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.Path   please? Also, if you want to ensure that there is active workbook, do _xlapp.Workbooks(1).Activate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a new instance of excel application because you already have one, where your addin is running. You need to use
 `Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application`
 instead.
This will get an object of application where your addin is loaded and you will be able to get all it's methods and properties (like `xlApp.ActiveSheet` or `xlApp.ActiveWorkbook`).

Comment: Indeed it works, i had to include it in  the Solution but it accomplishes the propose!!!!! THANKS A LOT!!!